# Pass script commands/input to opened WinSCP shell

Tags: cmd, winscp

I am trying to automate a file transfer using `WinSCP.com` which is kinda a shell that has its commands and arguments. 
But the automated script would be run from a `.cmd` or `.bat` file.

Therefore, here is my automation script:

```
C:
CD "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP"
CALL WinSCP.com   

REM This opens a   
REM   winscp>
REM shell or process

REM now theoretically I should be able to run the WinSCP commands
REM but they are not being piped into the winscp shell

open mypassword | myuser@myserver

REM the last command is not being executed.
REM Instead the script hangs on the newly opened WinSCP shell. 
REM There are other winscp commands such as put <file> <path>
```

My question is how do I tell WinSCP process to take the command `open mypassword | myuser@myserver` from the batch script file?

Oh and extra: I would like at the end to kill the `winscp` process\shell. I don't know the right terminology here. Is it process or shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [WinSCP `/command` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting), if you want to have the WinSCP commands in the batch file (rather than in a separate script file referenced using the `/script` switch).

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /command ^
    "open sftp://myuser:mypassword@myserver/" ^
    "..."
    "exit"
```

You can have [WinSCP GUI generate a batch file template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script) (like the one above).

---

While the use of the `/command` switch is recommended, what you actually asked for was something like this:

```
(
    echo open sftp://myuser@myserver/
    echo mypassword
    ...
    echo exit
) | winscp.com
```

Note that the behavior will be different in some situations, comparing to the `/commands`, as WinSCP assumes an interactive (human) use, when the commands are provided on the standard input. That's why you should use the `/commands`.